# Eloquent Query Dynamically based on json

Tags: php, laravel

I want to query dynamically based on payload(json) from database.

Example:

```
$data = [{"key":"age","relation":">","value":"15"},{"operator":"OR"},{"key":"age","relation":"<=","value":"20"}]
```

I want to do query based on that payload.

Right now what I'm doing is:

```
$query = User::all();
$payload = json_decode($data, true);
foreach($payload as $value){
    if ($value['key'] == 'age') {
                $query = $query->where('birthday', $value['relation'], Carbon::now()->subYears($value['age'])->format('Y-m-d');)
            }

    if($value['key'] == 'gender'{
        $query = $query->where('gender', $value['relation'], $value['gender']);
    }
}
```

The problem is yes it can work, but I don't think this is best approach. I don't get any solution to use the "operator" key. Operator usage is to change `where` to `orWhere`.

Any solution or tips to make it call dynamically like this?. I want my column at DB neat and simple. I can only think this way.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are expecting queries to be straight forward or simple, you should prefer writing a raw query in this case. That will be more clean.

Comment: @VishalSh thanks for you suggestion. any example for raw query in my case?

Comment: @SSuhat Are you sending in `AND` operator as well in the payload?

Comment: @z3r0ck yes. you are correct. so  I can put key as many as i want.

Comment: @SSuhat What version of laravel you are using?

Comment: @z3r0ck Laravel 5.2 with latest update.

Comment: @SSuhat Okay, I will update my answer and demonstrate using eloquent meanwhile you can check out my answer.

Comment: @z3r0ck thanks a lot! that will be very helpful. I'm still try using your answer too.

Answer (score 2):

Encountering this problem, I would go with [Local Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes). In this approach You create a model method named `scopeJson()` or whatever you feel better with to handl all conditions inside. I tried to handle most conditions here not only single `where` and `orWhere`. I assumed that your payload contains only one builder at a time.

```
public function scopeJson($query, $json)
{
    $wheres = [
        'between' => ['whereBetween', 'not' => 'whereNotBetween'],
        'null'    => ['whereNull', 'not' => 'whereNotNull'],
        'or'      => ['orWhere', 'not' => 'orWhereNot'],
        'in'      => ['whereIn', 'not' => 'whereNotIn'],
        'and'     => ['where', 'not' => 'orWhereNot'],
        'raw'     => 'whereRaw'
    ];

    $builder = json_decode($json);

    if (count($builder) > 0) {
        $query->where(
            $builder[0]->key,
            $builder[0]->relation,
            $builder[0]->value
        );

        // notBetween, notNull, notOr, notIn, notAnd
        if (stripos($builder[1]->operator, 'not') !== false) {
            $whereCondition = $wheres[strtolower(substr($builder[1]->operator, 3))]['not'];
        } else {
            $whereCondition = $wheres[strtolower($builder[1]->operator)];
        }

        if (count($builder[2]) == 3) {
            if ($whereCondition == 'whereRaw') {
                $query->$whereCondition(implode(" ", $builder[2]));
            } else {
                // where, whereNot
                $query->$whereCondition(
                    $builder[2]->key,
                    $builder[2]->relation,
                    $builder[2]->value
                );
            }
        } elseif (count($builder[2]) == 2) {
            // whereBetween, whereNotBetween, where, whereNot
            $query->$whereCondition(
                $builder[2]->key,
                $builder[2]->value
            );
        } elseif (count($builder[2]) == 1) {
            // whereNull, whereNotNull, whereRaw
            $query->$whereCondition(
                $builder[2]->key ?? $builder[2]->value // PHP 7.0 Null Coalescing Operator
            );
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```

If this method is defined within your User's model then you can use it this way:

```
$users = User::json($data)->get();
```

***PS: Although it should work, I didn't test it.***

Answer (score 1):

You can do raw query like this.

```
$data = '[{"key":"age","relation":">","value":"15"},{"operator":"OR"},{"key":"age","relation":"<=","value":"20"}]';

$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE";

$payload = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($payload as $value) {
    if (isset($value['operator'])) {
        $query .= " " . $value['operator'];
    } else {
        if ($value['key'] == 'age') {
            $query .= " 'birthday' " . $value['relation'] . " " .  Carbon::now()->subYears($value['value'])->format('Y-m-d');
        }

        if ($value['key'] == 'gender') {
            $query .= " 'gender' " . $value['relation'] . " " . $value['gender'];
        }
    }
}
```

This results in a query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE 'birthday' > 2001-07-02 OR 'birthday' <= 1996-07-02
```

Of course, you might use `printf()` for formatting and making this cleaner in some other way but this will get you started hopefully.

Comment: hi .. but what if the `json array` is **empty**. That means if there is no condition given, then query will be `select * from tablename where` , will this query run ..?

Comment: A simple `if` check can achieve that. As i mentioned this is just a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable function name to add your `orWhere` logic:

```
$query = User::all();
$payload = json_decode($data, true);
$function = 'where';
foreach($payload as $value){
  if(isset($value['operator'])){
    $function = $value['operator'] == 'OR' ? 'orWhere' : 'where';
  } else {
    if ($value['key'] == 'age') {
      $query = $query->$function('birthday', $value['relation'], Carbon::now()->subYears($value['age'])->format('Y-m-d');)
    } else {
      $query = $query->$function($value['key'], $value['relation'], $value['value']);
    }
  }
}
```

As long as your json data doesn't match your database (ie. the json has `age` but the database has `birthday`) you will not be able to avoid having that if/else statement.  That custom logic will have to remain.

Answer (score 0):

**Ultimately this idea is its own limiter because the stored queries will have to represent the current state of the database.** This means that the maintenance cost of these queries will be significant the moment data is stored in a different way -- if you changed the column `birthday` to `date_of birth` all of your stored queries will break. Avoid this.

Instead this goal is better achieved by storing the queries on the Model using [Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes) and [Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships). If you still need a dynamic list of requests you can store keywords that are associated with the queries and loop through them.